# How to use regular expression in WatiN

Tags: regex, watin

I'm working on WatiN automation tool. I'm having problem in regular expression. I've situation where i have to enter some text and click on a button in the popup window. I'm using AttachToIE method and URL attribute("http://192.168.25.10:215/admin/SelectUsers.aspx?Type=FeedbackID=ef5ad7ef5490-4656-9669-32464aeba7cd") of the popup to attach to the popup.

The problem is each time the popup appears the ID value in the URL changes. So i'm not able to access the popup. can anyone plz help with this by giving me Regular Expression for the changing value of ID in the below URL
("http://192.168.25.10:215/admin/SelectUsers.aspx?Type=FeedbackID=ef5ad7ef5490-4656-9669-32464aeba7cd")

thanking you

Comment: There seems to be a mistake in your url. It appears to me that Type and ID should be 2 separate query strings, in other words: "?Type=Feedback&ID={guid}" instead of "?Type=FeedbackID={guid}"

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you have a URL with 2 query string parameters **Type** and **ID** and your pattern is:

```
"http://192.168.25.10:215/admin/SelectUsers.aspx?Type=Feedback&ID={some id}"
```

You can use the `Find.ByUrl()` attribute constraint method and pass it to `AttachToIE()` as shown below with the regex for matching that pattern.

```
string url = "http://192.168.25.10:215/admin/SelectUsers.aspx?Type=Feedback&ID="
Regex regex = new Regex(url + "[a-z0-9]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
IE ie = IE.AttachToIE(Find.ByUrl(regex));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string baseUrl ="http://192.168.25.10:215/admin/SelectUsers.aspx?Type=FeedbackID="
Regex urlIE= new Regex(baseUrl + "[\\wd]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
IE ie = IE.AttachToIE(Find.ByUrl(urlIE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with WatiN but it looks like it's runs on .Net so perhaps this might help?

```
var desiredId = "000000000000-0000-0000-000000000000";
var url = "http://192.168.25.10:215/admin/SelectUsers.aspx?Type=FeedbackID=ef5ad7ef5490-4656-9669-32464aeba7cd&someMoreStuff";
var pattern = @"(?i)(?<=FeedBackId=)[-a-z0-9]+";
var result = Regex.Replace(url, pattern, desiredId);
Console.WriteLine(result);

//Output:  http://192.168.25.10:215/admin/SelectUsers.aspx?Type=FeedbackID=000000000000-0000-0000-000000000000&someMoreStuff
```

The following pattern should have the same affect but is more defensive. It should only match stuff in the query string, it requires the id to be 35 characters and won't match similar parameter names like "PreviousFeedBackId".

```
var pattern = @"(?i)(?<=\?.*\bFeedBackId=)[-a-z0-9]{35,35}\b";
```

If you just want to extract the id:

```
var id = Regex.Match(url, pattern).Value;
Console.WriteLine(id);
//output: ef5ad7ef5490-4656-9669-32464aeba7cd
```

Answer (score 0):

WatiN has a feature where in we can use the url by neglecting the query string. Below is the code which is working fine for me.

string baseUrl = "http://192.168.25.10:215/admin/SelectUsers.aspx";
IE ie = IE.AttachToIE(Find.ByUrl(baseUrl,true));